# Android live wallpaper not showing in Google Play on my tablet

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, google-play

I wrote my first Android live wallpaper and published it in Google Play. I tested it first on my tablet (Manta MID001 with Android 2.2) by installing it from an apk file and it was working fine. I never had a chance to debug on this device, because the USB port is broken.

It has been more than a week since publishing, but I still can't see the wallpaper in Google Play when using my tablet. I can find it only from my PC, and it's available [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.bartoszwesolowski.ringlivewallpaperdemo). I can't even see the wallpaper, when finding my other app and choosing "more from this developer". What might possibly be wrong?

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.bartoszwesolowski.ringlivewallpaperdemo"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <service
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".service.RingWallpaperService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@layout/wallpaper" />
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am sure my tablet supports live wallpapers, because I was able to download and use a couple of them. I even run this particular wallpaper, installing it from an apk file and I encountered no problems.

I read other posts on StackOverflow suggesting to add the following lines to the manifest file:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I don't think they are necessary though, because these options are true by default according to [Filters on Google Play documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/filters.html):

> For applications that set either the android: minSdkVersion or
>   android: targetSdkVersion to 3 or lower, the 
>   element itself is undefined and no attributes are available. In this
>   case, Google Play assumes that the application is designed for
>   normal-size screens and shows the application to devices that have
>   normal or larger screens.
>
> When the either the android: minSdkVersion or android:
>   targetSdkVersion is set to 4 or higher, the default for all attributes
>   is "true". In this way, the application is considered to support all
>   screen sizes by default.